# What's the difference between "en-US" and "auto:en-US" in web.config globalization settings?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, iis, web-config, globalization

web.config allows to set "culture" and "uiCulture":

```
<system.web>
    <globalization uiCulture="en-US" culture="en-US" />
```

Some samples I saw use just string like "en-US" which specifies a locale. Other use "auto:" prefix:

```
culture="auto:en-US"
```

I cannot find any reasonably looking explanation on how this should work.

What's the difference between the two - what does "auto:" prefix mean here?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [reference source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/HttpApplication.cs,1ee4fa636c663af4,references), with `auto:` it would attempt to use the client's `Accept-Language`, if not it will fall back to the specified culture. See: https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2014/Mar/27/Auto-Selecting-Cultures-for-Localization-in-ASPNET

Comment: So it looks like it there's no "auto:" then it will just use the culture specified in the config no matter what the user asks for.